# Backbone.js converting object from this to that and calling using each throw errror

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone function i made a name space for me as `var taskListPhraseI = {};` in using this name space all my function are assigned.

while i fetching the collection from collection class, using the each function i am passing to `renderBoard`, in the each will not aware about the `this` key word on this point, i used a variable declared as that and assigned to this, using `that` i am calling the function, but the `render function` throw the error as

```
TypeError: that.renderBoard is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

that.renderBoard(item)
```

but i do have the renderBoard function. any give me a clue to solve this?

my part of code :

```
 taskListPhraseI.allView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('.boardHolder'),
    initialize:function(){
      this.collection = new taskListPhraseI.collection();
      this.collection.fetch({success:this.render});
    },
    render:function(data){
      var that = this;
      _.each(data.models, function(item){
          that.renderBoard(item) // throw the error..
      },this);
    },
    renderBoard:function(item){
      console.log('item'); // i am not getting the call here...
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `this.collection.fetch({success:this.render});` with `this.collection.fetch({success:_.bind(this.render, this)});`.

You are passing function `this.render` without its context, which can be fixed by [`bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) in underscore library.

Comment: as a information, already my render function works fine, from the render function i unable to call renderBoard..

Comment: Have you tried my solution? `render` function itself is correct, but `fetch` function should pass the correct context `this` to `success` callback function.

Comment: yes, this is works. can you give some feed on this issue?, while i passed stuff to render this is the responsibility of render to pass to renderboard, so what is work here for fetch?

Comment: I added `bind` link in my answer, hoping that helps.

Comment: yes i got. thanks for your quick replay. i am just beginning my project with backbone as a fresher.

Comment: @3gwebtrain use _.bindAll(this) in your initialize to bind all functions' context to this in the collection/model/view

Comment: `bindAll` is convenient, but I would rather bind methods one by one to avoid unexpected results.